# Non-contiguous ranges in Excel solver

Tags: excel-formula, solver, named-ranges

Can the excel solver handle non-contiguous ranges in a constraint? For example, I want to have decision variables in **A1:A5,A7:A10**. The solver interface accepts this as a range for decision variables, but if I then want to add a constraint that these variables should be explicitly made nonzero (or any other restriction), the "Add constraint" validator claims that "*Cell Reference box is empty or contents are not valid.*" I get the same error if I use a named range reference instead of the direct string "**A1:A5,A7:A10**". Do I really have to split the constraint into two separate constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello I also faced this issue,
And as a work around, you can make the the combination in a different cell then use it in solver as your cell reference for your constraint.
you can refer to this link.
https://www.solver.com/solver-tutorial-defining-constraints

"General Constraints
Suppose that cells A1:A5 contain the percentage of funds to be invested in each of 5 stocks. We would want the sum of these cells to equal 1 (or 100%).  To accomplish this, in cell B1 you might calculate the sum of the percentages as =SUM(A1:A5) and then use solver to define a constraint to require that cell B1 = 1."